# Get Element from Object

Tags: jquery, object, select, element

I've got this

```
var fou = foubar.getContent();
```

where `getContent` is

> Returns a jQuery object wrapping the dialog's content region - everything inside the frame, excluding the title bar.

Thing is there are textbox values inside of fou I'd like to get at.
I've tried this below, but it doesn't work.

```
  fou.$('#textbox1').val();
```

How can I select elements of `fou`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `$('#textbox1',fou).val();`

Comment: FWIW, the context param causes an implicit call to .find().  Your answer actually gets turned into $( fou ).find( '#textbox1' ).val().  So it is more efficient to just use find() yourself. What's worse is that in the OP's situation, 'fou' is already a jQ collection, so it doesn't need passing into the $() factory--but that is just what will happen when it is passed as context.

Answer (score 1):

If `fou` really is a jQuery object, you can use [`find` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var value = fou.find('#textbox1').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find as shown below:

```
  fou.find( '#textbox1' );
```

Answer (score 0):

if the textbox is a child element of fou you can do:

```
$(fou.children('#textbox1')).val();
```